# jquery change event - what's wrong?

Tags: jquery

Simple question -

When I run the below (really trivial mocked up so I can post here) page in Firefox (haven't tested others) I get a "ready" alert, but I never get a change event from the select element. I've got code on other pages where this seems to work.

I see no errors in firebug or in FF's error console. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<select id="SeachFor" name="SearchFor">
<option id="0" value="0" selected="selected">Customer Number</option>
<option id="1" value="1">Email Address</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("ready");
        $("#SearchFor").change(function (evt) {
            alert("changed");

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The ID of your field is `id="SeachFor"` (missing `r`). Hence `$("#SearchFor")` will not find any element.

Comment: Lol, yeah, I see that now. What's really weird is, I swear firebug found a result for $("#SearchFor"). Been pulling my hair out over this and of course it's something stupid.

Comment: obviously not enough caffeine yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `SeachFor` to `SearchFor`, simple typo.

```
<select id="SearchFor" name="SearchFor">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Customer Number</option>
 <option value="1">Email Address</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5FWW/

Comment: Ha it's always the simple things!

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e forggoten "r" in the id. SeachFor <> SearchFor.

With "r": http://jsfiddle.net/fkkS9/

Answer (score 0):

You've miss-spelt the id in your select tag -

```
<select id="SeachFor" name="SearchFor">
```

should be

```
<select id="SearchFor" name="SearchFor">
```